# Problem with converting .class file into .dex file

Tags: java

I was truing to convert .class file to .dex file, but got error.
When I type in cmd "dx --dex --output=(.dex file path) (.class file path)" I got error:

*CreateProcess failed:
[3] ╤шёЄхьх эх єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ яєЄ№.
ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads
If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.
You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html*

(my JAVA_HOME path is in JDK folder:

C:\Program Files>echo %JAVA_HOME%

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\JDK

also the path to .dex file and .class file doesn't contain any cyrillic letters)

Maybe I need to try another Java JDK version?

Comment: What is the output of `%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe -version`?

Comment: The version of java.exe file is 15.0.1.0

Comment: Try adding the bin directory of the JDK to your `PATH`.

Comment: I did as you said, now one part of the error (CreateProcess failed: [3] ╤шёЄхьх эх єфрхЄё  эрщЄш єърчрээ√щ яєЄ№.) is gone, but other part of  the error (ERROR: No suitable Java found...) still exist